# Azure API App Login & Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have searched the web over almost one week and I couldn't find a solution for the question.

I set everything on the azure portal for the authentication the claims and the principals are set that for sure after I checks it during the debug session. The only thing is missing! I cannot retrieve/get the jwt token from the below url.
The authentication is obviously successfully. I would be glad if someone can lighten me up on this.

> https://dev.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done#token=%7B%22authenticationToken%22%3A%22**eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdGFibGVfc2lkIjoic2lkOjJmMDg1ZWY1NDM0MzNlZDM1MzNkYTRkMDgyNGFlY2QyIiwic3ViIjoic2lkOmZjMzhmNGExZjI2ZDI5MTdhMTQzZWMyZDMyZjAwOWIyIiwiaWRwIjoiZmFjZWJvb2siLCJ2ZXIiOiIzIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtZjFhZGQwNGUtZjNjZC0xMWU3LWI0ZTktOWEyMTRjZjA5M2FlLmF6dXJld2Vic2l0ZXMubmV0LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZGV2LWYxYWRkMDRlLWYzY2QtMTFlNy1iNGU5LTlhMjE0Y2YwOTNhZS5henVyZXdlYnNpdGVzLm5ldC8iLCJleHAiOjE1MjA1Mzc1NTUsIm5iZiI6MTUxNTM1NzQ5MH0.z0Ys8dwKO_napvy4Ihfu39mHc6zyBpJIUjSzZWj8abI**%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22userId%22%3A%22sid%3Afc38f4a1f26d2917a143ec2d32f009b2%22%7D%7

If I create a new token from the principal it's working but I cannot get the data from the .auth/me service. I'm not using AD at all just google and facebook to authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I realized that I tried to solve the problem from wrong direction.

I tried to get the token from the server Api App service I wrote. Instead of using one of the client library as Bruce told me. I missed the **Javascript/HTML** documentation part which was not in the main tree but under Cordova. I have only seen the **Cordova**, **Android** and **IOS** which was not good for me.

With the following link now I can get the token from the website with the Javascript client SDK!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing is missing! I cannot retrieve/get the jwt token from the below url.

You could url decode your url and retrieve the `authenticationToken` property generated by your azure mobile app backend as the authentication token for your subsequent requests against your mobile app backend.

When decoding your `authenticationToken` jwt token, I found that the `iss` and `aud` do not equal your domain `dev.azurewebsites.net`.

[image]

> If I create a new token from the principal it's working but I cannot get the data from the .auth/me service.

If you login via the browser (e.g. `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{provider-name} e.g. facebook,google,etc.`), after logged you could directly access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` via the browser. Or you could send the token along with your request as follows:

```
GET https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me
Header x-zumo-auth:{authenticationToken}
```

And for non web browser based client, such as mobile, a JSON web token (JWT) would be presented in the X-ZUMO-AUTH header, and the Mobile Apps client SDKs would handle it for you. Details you could follow [How authentication works in App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview#how-authentication-works-in-app-service).

Moreover, for generating the token by yourself, you need to correctly set the `audience`,`issuer`,`signingKey`,`claim`. Details you could follow adrian hall's book [Custom authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/#custom-authentication) about the `Post` method under the `CustomAuthController` controller.

Comment: Today I realized my first mistake maybe I was not clear on my request also not realized that after the fragment sign the token is not sent to the server at all. Myproblem is how I can get authenticationToken to authenticate the request from not mobile sdk but from the web api  controller if I do a login with the provider. Maybe my expression is wrong how the authentication works with the Azure authentication and I need a custom authentication as you mentioned.